# Can unsigned integer vaule is there in java? if then how to declare it?

Tags: java, integer

Can we have unsigned Integer value in java?If value is there then how to declare it.

Comment: Java does not have unsigned values, see this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381015/unsigned-integer-in-java

Comment: Please search before posting. And consider some Java tutorials.